# sqlalchemy filter() Table instance

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

this feels basic but for the life of me I can't figure it out

I got the following table:

```
class Node(BaseModel):
    __tablename__ = "node"
    id = sqla.Column(sqla.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = sqla.Column(sqla.String)
    ntype = sqla.Column(sqla.String)
    .... 
    many more columns
    ...
```

and I want to find a way to search by providing a table instance instead of having to filter(_and(Node. == )._and(....))

however, the experiment below doesn't work and I haven't found out how it should be.

```
    node = Node(id=0,name="1",ntype="2")
    qu = Node.query(node)
    frst = qu.first()
    pprint(frst)
    pprint(str(qu))
    pprint(node)
```

the above throws the following exception:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: SQL expression object expected, got object of type <class 'application.database.db.Node'
```

if I replace line 2 with

```
qu = Node.query.filter(Node==node)
```

the query becomes the following instead of matching the table attributes with the instance variables

```
('SELECT node.id AS node_id, node.name AS node_name,node.ntype AS node_ntype FROM node WHERE 0 = 1')
```

is there a way to provide a sqlalchemy query with an object and perform a Select based on the object?

Comment: Filters are based on attribute values, so your query would be `q  = Node.filter(Node.id==0,Node.name=="1",Node.ntype=="2")`.  Though since `id` is a primary key, you could pass only `id` to the filter and get the same result.  I don't understand what you would expect passing an object would achieve - even if it worked, the query would just return the same object.

Comment: thanks for the comment, is there a better way to compare whole objects, maybe without using filter()? I ideally would like to just provide a Node() object and sqlalchemy to select based on the values that have been set

Answer (score 0):

i ended up with:

```
@classmethod
def object_select(cls,node:Node)->List[Node]:
    if not node:
        return []
    qu = Node.query.filter()
    for vk, v in vars(node).items():
        if hasattr(Node,vk):
            if v:
                attr = getattr(Node,vk)
                qu = qu.filter(attr==v)
        else:
            logger.debug(f"{vk} not in Node")
    return qu.all()
```